# Cats don't know how to mate

Tags: cats, behavior, breeding, reproduction

My Persian male cat is 1 year and a month old. Two days ago, one of our close friend brought her Persian female cat, because Queen was in heat, who also is 1 year and a month old. Tom is 10 days older than the Queen.

It was difficult at first, but after some hours they were comfortable with each other.

The problem is since it is first time experience for both Tom and Queen, they don't know how to mate. Queen tries to raise her bottom up, but my Tom is having a hard time getting the positions right. He bites the neck, and mostly humps on the back of the middle of Queen's spine. It seems, even they are frustrated because they cannot mate. Also, Tom is larger than the Queen.

Since it has been two days, is there anything I can do to help? Or is it too soon for both of them. Could you please advice. Even I am sad listening to my Tom cry because he cannot full fill nature's order.

Comment: I never had my cats mated so I won't attempt to answer. But 1 year and 1 month is equivalent of 16 years in human age and two 16 year old teenagers would have such difficulties as well. It might be a little too early, I never heard of any friend mating their cats before they are two.

Comment: I find it actually somewhat cute, even though I understand and agree that it might be concerning. But there is a 100% certainty that all the ancestors of these cats had figured it out at some point of their lives, literally all of them, and I can't think of any other skill in case of which one could say anything even remotely similar. Nature has literally always been preferring those who could reproduce and efficiently do so, therefore I'd expect them to eventually figure it out on their own, too.

Comment: Of course, there is a little chance that either of these cats is different - for example, there could be some underlying medical disorder disrupting the course of nature.

Comment: @C.Koca I never thought of it this way. Is it okay to separate them now? Do you think it will harm their behaviour in the long run?

Comment: @lila Yes, I too was hoping nature would do its thing.

Comment: @Kakar It should be alright. Cats usually remember their partner or sibling for at least fifteen days, maybe much more. Even if they forget each other you can reintroduce them again.

Comment: I am sorry that my comment wasn't helpful and didn't really attempt solving your issue, I just don't know how to possibly solve this so at least I just wanted to help you cheering up a little about this. I hope that someone comes in with a good answer soon, or that your cat will figure it out with your friend's queen.